# Not able to click button inside the Frame and getting error as “org.openqa.selenium.WeddriverException”

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

Issue: Not able to click button inside the Frame and getting error as

> org.openqa.selenium.WeddriverException:unknown error: Element is not clickable at point(66,385). Other element would receive the the click… display: block;>….

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/select/option[1]")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/select/option[5]")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button/span[contains( text(),'View Report')]")).click();
```

NOTE 1: Able to click dropdown values but not able to click “View Report” button
NOTE 2: Button is clicked in Selenium IDE but not clicked in Java Webdriver.

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully? It tells you what happened. You aren't clicking a `BUTTON`, you are clicking a `SPAN`. If you are going to provide an error message, you need to tell us which line it occurs on. You should look into `WebDriverWait` as a replacement for `Thread.sleep()` because it's not good practice to use them like this. Your XPaths are also very fragile since they are starting at the html tag. Any change anywhere up that chain will break your automation.

Comment: Could you share your HTML code for "View Report" button????...and why are you going to click on `span` insteadof `button`....is provided `span` is clickable...this might be problem....you need to try to click on button using this XPath : `//span[contains( text(),'View Report')]/parent::button`....may be it will help...

Comment: @Jeff - I have tried with below Webdriver code and it's not working.


WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div/button/span[contains( text(),'View Report')]")));
 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button/span[contains( text(),'View Report')]")).click();

Comment: @Saurabh - I have tried your xpath: //span[contains( text(),'View Report')]/parent::button and its not clicked.
Please find below HTML code,

Comment: is there same exception???? and did you test this `xPath` on browser console to verify it's correct or not?? means this `xPath` locate to `View Report` or not

Comment: And where could I found HTML code??

Comment: Yes Saurabh, Am getting same exception. And also I tried xpath in console and its getting blank square bracket "[ ]" .

Comment: HTML code:
<button class="pentaho-button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">View Report</span>
</button >

Comment: Ok means provided `XPath` is correct..due to frame you found `[]` at browser console when using `XPath`...so no problem if the exception is same that element is not clickable...means you are finding the element..only problem is in `click`...so in this situation you can use `JavaSriptExecutor` to perform click..see my answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(0);
 // your steps
 // now going to find button

 WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains( text(),'View Report')]/parent::button"));
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

**Note**:- For best practice you should use `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions` to wait for visibility of element insteadof `Thread.sleep`..

Hope it will help you to perform `click`...:)

Comment: Button is clicked after using JavaScript Executor. Thanks Saurabh for helping with this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a click for options. You can use select option in selenium.

Please find the below code for further clarity

```
WebElement identifier =driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/select));
Select select = new Select(identifier );
select.selectByIndex(1);
select.selectByVisibleText("View Report");
select.selectByValue("View Report");
```

Not only selectByindex you can also use selectByVisibleText , selectByValue
Please try

Comment: Hi Pramod, 
Dropdown values are selectable but only issue with "View Report" button.